# html table cell content as clickable link not firing when URL contains space

Tags: html, hyperlink, onclick, html-table

I have a very strange problem with an HTML table.

One of the cells contains on onclick event to open another page but it is not firing when part of the url contains a space character, e.g.: cell contains:

```
onClick=document.location.href="mypage.html?pid=abc123&sid=123" // --> this opens the page ok

onClick=document.location.href="mypage.html?pid=abc 123&sid=456" // --> this does nothing at all and gives me an error in the browser console "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal".
```

Anyone have any ideas what the problem is and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
onclick='document.location.href="mypage.html?pid=abc 123&sid=456"'
```

You should encapsulate the whole value of `onclick` in `'` characters.

Answer (score 0):

try encodeURIComponent()

```
onClick='document.location.href=encodeURIComponent("mypage.html?pid=abc 123&sid=456")'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it gives me an error that it cannot find the URL when I encode it.